# Passing null values in sendKeys()

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am reading data from excel sheet and passing those values into the application using sendKeys(). But when I am trying to pass any null values using sendKeys(), I am getting "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: keys should be a string" error. Please help me, how can I pass null values using sendKeys().

Comment: Do people send null values using their keyboard? Think about it.

Comment: I have a scenario that, I am iterating some steps and among those steps for one iteration, I have to keep a field as blank. So for that particular field when my framework is executing the step, it is trying to send null value.

Comment: Sending `null` is not leaving a field blank (you can't do it anyway). Check if the value is `null`, if it is don't do anything.

Comment: Or cast the value to string and send an empty string instead so finally you end up with an empty input. But I'd go for Guy's solution. Just don't do anything if the value is `null`, it's much more logical.

Comment: Thanks emix after casting the value to String my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You don't send nulls

As mentioned in the comments, a user cannot send a `null` via their keyboard, so Selenium won't do it either.

Instead, you should be doing some sort of filtering when reading in values from an external source (a good practice even beyond dealing with nulls).

In your filter, if the cell field is blank (null), then you should do one of two things:

1. Send nothing
2. Send an empty string; ""

Actually, you should have filters for both. There will be times you don't want to send anything and there will be times where you want to send "" to blank out the current value.

I personally have it set up so if the cell is blank, send "", and if the cell says "null", then don't send any values.